# Why does `checkInputlength` always returns false?

Tags: javascript

```
var button = document.querySelector("button");
var input = document.querySelector("input");
var ul = document.querySelector("ul");
var checkInputlength = input.value.length>0;

function createList() {
  if (checkInputlength) {
    var node = document.createTextNode(input.value);
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.appendChild(node);
    ul.appendChild(li);
  }
}

button.addEventListener("click", createList);
```

`checkInputlength` always returns false for some reason. But, when I put the condition inside the if statement`if (input.value.length>0)`, it works as expected. Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: You're initializing `checkInputLength` when that code loads. It gets initialized to `false` up front (when the input presumably has no value) and then nothing ever changes it.

Comment: You should only evaluate `input.value.length` when the button is clicked, not at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have mentioned, you are initializing `checkInputlength` to `false` when the scripts runs the first time and never again checking that logic.

However, you've named the variable in an interesting way, it seems as though you want it to be a function, so if you just put the logic of `checkInputlength` inside a function, then you can call it the same way you're calling the `checkInputlength` variable inside the createList, see the following:

```js
var button = document.querySelector("button");
var input = document.querySelector("input");
var ul = document.querySelector("ul");
var checkInputlength = () => input.value.length > 0; // Now a function

function createList() {
  if (checkInputlength()) { // that can be called like this
    var node = document.createTextNode(input.value);
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.appendChild(node);
    ul.appendChild(li);
  }
}

button.addEventListener("click", createList);
```

```html
<input type="text" /><button>Button</button>
<ul></ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

What you have done is checked the length of the `<input>`'s value once and saved the result as a variable. It will not change on subsequent lookups of that variable. In a sense you have cached the value, or frozen it in time by looking it up once (and only once) when the length of the input's value was 0.

See this example. As you type in the input you will see your variable does not change, but the value returned from the function does.

```js
var input = document.querySelector("input");
var checkInputlength = input.value.length>0;

function returnBooleanAboutInputLength() {
  return input.value.length>0;
}

setInterval(()=>{
  console.log("returnBooleanAboutInputLength()", returnBooleanAboutInputLength())
  console.log("checkInputlength", checkInputlength)
}, 1000)
```

```html
<input>
```

Answer (score 0):

You initialized

```
var checkInputlength = input.value.length>0;
```

before that you execute code on the click

```
button.addEventListener("click", createList);
```

Just put initializing inside of function and it will works:

```
function createList() {
  let checkInputlength = input.value.length > 0;
  if (checkInputlength) {
    var node = document.createTextNode(input.value);
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.appendChild(node);
    ul.appendChild(li);
  }
}
```